# Embedded Linux USB driver for SAM7 serial

Tags: serial-port, usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have a device using an Atmel processor running under Linux. To this device I want to connect a remote device using a AT91SAM7 processor. This remote device is configured to do a pseudo-serial over the USB, under Windows this works fine and shows up as "AT91 USB to Serial Converter (COM3)".

Under Linux the device appears in the /dev as following:

```
crw-rw----    1 root     root     253,   7 Aug 30 10:52 /dev/usbdev2.2_ep00
crw-rw----    1 root     root     253,   5 Aug 30 10:52 /dev/usbdev2.2_ep01
crw-rw----    1 root     root     253,   6 Aug 30 10:52 /dev/usbdev2.2_ep82
crw-rw----    1 root     root     253,   4 Aug 30 10:52 /dev/usbdev2.2_ep83
```

What must I do in order to communicate with the device? Some driver to bind into the kernel? Or does a loadable driver (.ko) exist?

Comment: If there are any `/dev/ttyUSB*` devices?

Comment: You over-use the word "device".  First you wrote *"To this device I want to connect a remote device", but then it's *"What must I do in order to communicate with the device?"*  If this (remote?) device really emulates a serial device over USB, then you apparently need to adapt one of the [USB serial drivers](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/usb/serial/).

Answer (score 0):

Based on what yo wrote, the embedded board with the AT91SAM7 processor is correctly configured, since it works when you connect it to a windows host.

If it does not work under linux, probably it is due to the fact that it does not recognize the vendorid:productid values.

On the linux host check the output of `lsusb`:

```
ottavio@ottavio:~$ lsusb 
Bus 004 Device 006: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
ottavio@ottavio:~$
```

in this case, that a USB<->RS232 converter I have on my computer. You should have a line related to your board when you plug it.

Now, depending on your system you may need to user `usbserial` or `ftdi_sio`. So try first to load usbserial

```
modprobe usbserial vendor=0x067b product=0x2303
```

if this does not work try loading ftdi_sio

```
modprobe ftdi_sio vendor=0x067b product=0x2303
```

Pay attatention that if the modules are already loaded you need to `rmmod` them. Finally, in my example vendrid is 0x067b and product is 0x2303, you'll need to use the correct values.